# Parse JSON in Tizen Web App with TAU Library

Tags: javascript, json, tizen, tizen-web-app

Is there a simple way to parse a JSON with TAU library? I couldn't find any solution.

I'm trying to get data from alphavantage api and display it: `www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo`

I've tried XMLhttprequest and Jquery and none seems to work with Tizen Web App.

Comment: Please post your code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up the config.xml as recommended above by @Patryk Falba,

I've come up with two working options:

**Using fecth()**

```js
if (self.fetch) {
  console.log("Fetching...")
  fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data['Global Quote']['01. symbol'])
    })

} else {
  console.log("Something went wrong...")
}
```

**Using XMLHttpRequest()**

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log("Ok!");
    console.log(myObj['Global Quote']['01. symbol']);
  }
};

xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo', true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 3):

To access external resources You need to add *internet* **privilege** and define *access origin* (both in `config.xml`):

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

and

```
<access origin="https://www.alphavantage.co" subdomains="true"/>
```

then You can simply get data with Fetch API:

```
fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonData => { console.log(jsonData) });
```